# Sorting doesn't work on WPF DataGrid templated columns?

Tags: wpf, datagrid, wpfdatagrid, datagridtemplatecolumn

I noticed that sorting always do not work on DataGrid templated columns, is there any solution for this problem?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to set the `SortMemberPath="PropertyName"` property in your templated DataGrid column.

Comment: Notice that it's just the property name, it's not a binding expression.